# or condition in while loop python

Tags: python, while-loop

Does or condition work in a while loop in python? I can't seem to make it work. This is the sample of how my code works.

```
newslot = 3
moved = False

while newslot > 0 or moved != True:
    enabled = query something on the database where slot = newslot
    if enabled:
        print 'do something here'
        moved = True
    else:
        newslot-=1
        print 'slot disabled'
```

So when the newslot gets to value of zero it still proceeds to go inside the while loop. 
I seem to be missing something here.

Comment: What isn't working? Also, what is the value of `slot`?

Comment: What are the values of `slot` and `enabled`?

Comment: `or` is working but if `slot is enabled` is True then, your loop never ends since `newslot > 0` remains True

Comment: but does `or` meant that if one statement is true, the while loop will end? @JulienSpronck

Comment: @test NO. it will continue when either one is True. You need `and` instead of `or`

Comment: `or` means when at least one statement is `True` the while loop will continue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`or` is working as should be expected. A `while` loop will continue until its condition is false. If its condition is two separate conditions connected with an `or`, it will only be false when the two conditions are both false.

Your loop will continue repeating until `moved` is false and `newslot` is <= 0. I'm guessing you actually want to use `and` in this case, as you want the loop to stop once either condition is met.

Comment: well that was confusing, i thought when I used `or`, i didnt have to satisfy both conditions, anyway thanks for the help, i will use `and` instead.

Comment: @test A while loop will continue as long as its condition is true. If you have two conditions connected with an `or`, the loop will only end once both are false, as if one is true then the entire `or` is true.

Comment: I see, thats stupid of me. I thought the other way around. Thanks alot for clarifying. @StephenTG

Comment: @test No problem, happy to help