# Exit function in python

Tags: python

```
import random
import sys

player_oneN = input("Enter Name for Player One")
player_twoN = input("Enter Name for Player Two")
player_oneS = 0
player_twoS = 0
if player_oneN == "stop" or "exit":
    c = int(input("Press 1 to continue and 0 to quit :"))
    if c == 0:
        sys.exit()
if player_twoN == "stop" or "exit":
    c = int(input("Press 1 to continue and 0 to quit :"))
    if c == 0:
        sys.exit()
```

whenever I try to run this code the options to exit the program always displays. I only want this option to come available when the user enters exit or stop in the player one and player two input.

Comment: Please provide more about context of this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [or condition in while loop python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994187/or-condition-in-while-loop-python)

Comment: try `if player_oneN in ["stop", "exit"]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `or` conditions are incorrect and just check that `exit` is not `null` which is always true.

```
import random
import sys

player_oneN = input("Enter Name for Player One")
player_twoN = input("Enter Name for Player Two")
player_oneS = 0
player_twoS = 0
if player_oneN == "stop" or player_oneN == "exit": # <--- should be this
    c = int(input("Press 1 to continue and 0 to quit :"))
    if c == 0:
        sys.exit()
if player_twoN == "stop" or player_twoN == "exit": # <--- should be this
    c = int(input("Press 1 to continue and 0 to quit :"))
    if c == 0:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `in` and check against a list of items when you want to check for multiple values in an if statement.

```
import random
import sys

player_oneN = input("Enter Name for Player One")
player_twoN = input("Enter Name for Player Two")
player_oneS = 0
player_twoS = 0
if player_oneN.lower() in ["stop", "exit"]: # replace with in list items
    c = int(input("Press 1 to continue and 0 to quit :"))
    if c == 0:
        sys.exit()
if player_twoN.lower() in ["stop", "exit"]: # replace with in list items
    c = int(input("Press 1 to continue and 0 to quit :"))
    if c == 0:
        sys.exit()
```

Since both your if statements are doing the same thing, you can combine them into one if statement.

```
if player_oneN.lower() in ["stop", "exit"] or player_twoN.lower() in ["stop", "exit"]:
    c = int(input("Press 1 to continue and 0 to quit :"))
    if c == 0:
        sys.exit()
```

You can also do something like this:

```
if any(i in ['stop','end'] for i in [player_oneN.lower(),player_twoN.lower()]):
    c = int(input("Press 1 to continue and 0 to quit :"))
    if c == 0:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `player_twoN == "stop" or "exit"` is not doing what you're expecting. Its being interpreted as `(player_twoN == "stop") or "exit"`. Since a non-empty string evaluates to `True`, the whole statement evaluates to `True`.